# Crystal Reports: how to repeat Details A section on every page

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm creating a report in Crystal. It's a pretty basic report: I have two groups based on the same date field: year and month.

Those two groups serve as a way of organizing my details. I have the details hidden so they can be drilled down upon. 
So when you first view the report, you just see the year(s) for group 1, and then the months for group 2.

If I wasn't using the grouped dates in this way, and was just creating a basic table, I would put the field headers in the page header section, which would automatically put the field headers on every page. However, since I have the grouped dates (hiding the details) on my first page, I can't put the field headers in there.

As a result, I created two detail sections (A and B). I put my field headers in A with the suppress formula (not onfirstrecord). This serves my purpose, but for when the report details fill up multiple pages, my Details A sections will only display on the first page.

Is there some formula or other way for me to:

1) Keep my field headers in Details A, but repeat the field headers on each new page?

2) or, move my field headers to the Page Header section, but somehow suppress it when my groups are being displayed on my main page (where the year and month groups can be drilled down on)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a *repeated group header*.

To do this open the `Change Group Options` dialog (right click on a group header, then choose `Change Group`). On the Options tab check `Repeat Group Header On Each Page`.

Put your headers for your detail section in a group header (maybe an additional one just for this purpose). Repeat this header on each page.

You can even detect if the header is printed the first time or if it is repeated using `InRepeatedGroupHeader`. This way you can implement a 'continued' on a repeated group header.